# How to configure checkstyle in eclipse using m2e automatically?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, checkstyle, m2e

I've read posts about configuring checkstyle using the m2eclipse plugin, but it seems its not working for the new m2e plugin maintained by eclipse.

Is there a way for using the same checkstyle configuration rules in maven and eclipse automatically without falling back to maven-eclipse-plugin?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The m2e checkstyle plugin, which lives at https://github.com/organizations/m2e-code-quality, is a little behind on releases and advertisement in the marketplace. You could build your own copy and install the plugins in eclipse.